# What does 'the agent has no identities' mean?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I succesfully followed [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) from GitHub on how to generate SSH keys and my connection with GitHub is succesfull.

But when I later want to check my SSH key following [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-ssh-keys-and-application-access-tokens-safe/) I don't get the SSH fingerprint I see in my GitHub SSH Keys setting page when I use `ssh-add -l`.

Instead of the SSH key fingerprint I get the message `The agent has no identities.` Why? And what does it mean?

Comment: Aside: This isn't really a programming question -- SSH identities are used for many purposes unrelated to software development, and the question itself has nothing to do with writing code; I'd probably have asked it on http://www.superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 16):

This means you haven't successfully added your key to your agent. Use `ssh-add` to do so, as given in step 3, part 2 of your first link.

Note that this needs to be done for each ssh-agent instance; thus, if you log out and back in, you need to `ssh-add` your key again. Similarly, if you start `ssh-agent` twice, in two different terminal windows, they won't have shared private keys between them, so you would need to `ssh-add` once in each window (or, better, configure your system in such a way as to have an agent shared between all running applications in your desktop session).

Modern desktop environments generally will provide a SSH keyring for you, so you shouldn't need to start `ssh-agent` yourself if your agent is so configured, and the agent instance so provided should be shared across your entire session. gnome-keyring behaves this way, as does Apple's keychain and KDE's Wallet (with ksshaskpass enabled).

Comment: What if `ssh-add` is the program generating the message?

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million, it generates that message only with the `-l` option. It won't generate that when used in a mode where its job is to add new keys.