# SSH forwarding does not work for vagrant

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-agent

I set up ssh params of Vagrant 1.8.1 as described [here](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/using-ssh-agent-forwarding-with-vagrant/)

Shortly, I got on host ssh config file:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bitbucket
  User zuba
  ForwardAgent yes
```

in Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

On host machine ssh-add -L shows the key, while on vagrant box it reports that the agent has no identities and git clone fails due to authentication failure

How to solve this issue?

**UPDATE 1:**

`vagrant ssh -c 'ssh-add -l'` shows the key

```
> vagrant ssh-config
Host p4
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/zuba/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
```

**UPDATE 2:**

found the duplicate post with no answers [vagrant ssh agent forwarding only works for inline commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611015/vagrant-ssh-agent-forwarding-only-works-for-inline-commands)

**UPDATE 3:**

Here it is my Vagrantfile:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  boxes = {
      "p4" => "10.2.2.15",
  }

  boxes.each do |box_name, box_ip|
    config.vm.define box_name do |config|
      config.vm.box = "trusty-64"
      config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"
      config.vm.hostname = "p4"
      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: box_ip
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3002, host: 3002
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3003, host: 3003
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6379 # Redis

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.name = "p4"

        # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
      end

      config.vm.synced_folder "../..", "/home/vagrant/my_src"
      config.ssh.forward_agent = true # to use host keys added to agent

      # provisioning
      config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get update"

      config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
        chef.log_level = "info"
        chef.environment = "development"
        chef.environments_path = "environments"
        chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks", "site-cookbooks"]
        chef.roles_path = "roles"
        chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
        chef.json.merge!(JSON.parse(IO.read("nodes/#{box_ip}.json")))
      end

      config.exec.commands '*', directory: '/home/vagrant'
      config.exec.commands 'apt-get', prepend: 'sudo'
      config.exec.commands %w[rails rspec rake], prepend: 'bundle exec'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you run vagrant in verbose to see what happens?

Comment: It is set, see above

Comment: Have you `vagrant reload` since modifying the Vagrantfile?

Comment: What command are you using to bring vagrant up?

Comment: Yes, I have reloaded it

Comment: I use `vagrant reload`

Comment: what does your `vagrant ssh-config` look like?

Comment: Strange, but `vagrant ssh -c 'ssh-add -l'` shows the key

Comment: Ok there is a --debug flag you can use that will output logging while it is attempting to connect.. So try `vagrant up --debug`

Comment: just added `vagrant ssh-config` output to the post above

Comment: Tried `vagrant up --debug` It dumpes a LOT. What shall I look for in that?

Comment: @zuba Are you really using vagrant v1.4? Try updating before debugging this further. Agent forwarding is [easy to setup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12085692/316622) and you've already done all that. Your `vagrant ssh-config` output is pointing `IdentityFile` to the wrong key. Pastebin your Vagrantfile.

Comment: Upgrade of vagrant from 1.4 to 1.8.1 doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: Added UPDATE3: Vagrantfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612977/what-does-the-agent-has-no-identities-mean) which helped me to figure out what prevented vagrant from using agents key.

I `ssh-add` the key in one **GNU screen session**, while doing `vagrant ssh` in another screen session. That is why ssh-agent was kinda 'inaccessible' to the vagrant.

When I added the key and ssh-ed vagrat in the same screen session, everything started working

Comment: Be aware that `ssh-agent` is per X-session or login session.